# Display a live numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, debugging, inspector

In APL, you can trivially bring up a window that shows the contents of a variable whilst your program is running and watch it update live.

This is illustrated by the classic [Game of Life](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a9xAKttWgP4) video at 5 minutes in.

Is there any similar 'inspector' for Python with support for numpy arrays so I can see step through my array code and see what its doing live?

(Ideally using TK or something portable)

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the python debugger? ([pdb](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html))

It's not graphical but it is completely portable. Depending what IDE you're using, there might be a visual debugger built in.

Answer (score 0):

(original poster)

[image]

I could not find one, so I made one.  [You can get it here](http://williamedwardscoder.tumblr.com/post/26090982537/debugwin-watch-windows-for-python).